# Как заменить Graphic из Java awt в какой-нибудь другой класс, но в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, awt

Есть код на Java awt. Есть метод, который отвечает на отрисовку конкретного объекта. И этот метод принимает Graphic. Как можно переписать этот метод, используя JavaFX?

```
void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (xonix.getCountLives() == 0) {
            gameOver = true;
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(new Font("", Font.BOLD, 60));
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            g.drawString(GAME_OVER_MSG, (FIELD_WIDTH*POINT_SIZE + FIELD_DX - fm.stringWidth(GAME_OVER_MSG))/2, (FIELD_HEIGHT*POINT_SIZE)/2);
        }
    }
```

Это один из примеров такого метода. Чем можно заменить этот Graphics g, но через JavaFX?

Comment: На [GraphicsContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html) замените.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> На GraphicsContext замените

[Canvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) - `Node` для размещения на сцене и поставляющий `GraphicContext`